# Jumping pair lines using .readLine() method at a while loop

Tags: java

I am new at Java and I am having a little trouble:

I am trying to read chemical samples to represent them at a X-Y graph.

The input file looks like this:

La 0.85678

Ce 0.473

Pr 62.839
...
...

My code stocks only the unpair lines value (0.85678, jumps line, 62.839 at the example), and I cannot realize what is the problem:

```
public class Procces {

   public void readREE() throws IOException {

           try{

           rEE = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("src/files/test.txt"));

           while   ( (currentLine = rEE.readLine() ) != null) {

               try  { 

                   for (int size = 3;size<10;size++) {

                       String valueDec=(currentLine.substring(3,size));
                       //char letra =(char)c;
                       if ((c=rEE.read()) != -1) {
                           System.out.println("Max size");
                       } else

                       valueD = Double.parseDouble(valueDec);
                       System.out.println(valueDec);
                       }
                   }
             catch (Exception excUncertainDecimals) {
                    }
                }              
           }finally {   
               try {  rEE.close();
                           } catch (Exception exc) {
                              }
           } 
   }
       String line;
       int c = 0;
       int counter = 0;
       String valueS = null;
       String valueSimb = null;
       Double valueD = null;
       Double logValue = null;
       Double YFin=450.0;
       String currentLine;
       BufferedReader rEE;
```

}

Thank you in advance, as I can't see why the program jumps the pair lines.

Comment: Please post your code correctly from your IDE. Eclipse can't make sense of your thing. Curly braces are missing everywhere.

Comment: Done. The method is inside a class that is going to plot the points, so it has extra variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Java Scanner class.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"))){

            while (s.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(s.next());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That simplifies a lot, and I can see the utility of using Scanner, so I think I will use it, aswell as J Excel open API for Excel files.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

In general is Java a well established language and in most cases you do not have to re-implemented "common" (e.g. reading custom text files) stuff on a low level way.

Comment: I became a bit crazy with the editor and I think I erased: "I would highly recommend to use apache poi for that. poi.apache.org You will find ton of thread regarding this here on stackoverflow ;-) hf".  I will take a look to apache API and to the forums, to read also excel files, the most commonly used. Now I am going to continue with the plotting just adding with scanner the .txt values.

Answer (score 0):

I get it. Thank you.

Here the code:

```
import java.io.*
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Process implements Samples{

   public void readREE() throws IOException {

           try
               (Scanner rEE = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/files/test.txt")))){
                   while (rEE.hasNext()) {

                       element = rEE.next();

                       if (element.equals("La")) {
                            String elementValue = rEE.next();
                            Double value = Double.parseDouble(elementValue); 
                            Double valueChond = 0.237;
                            Double valueNorm= value/valueChond;
                            Double logValue = (Math.log(valueNorm)/Math.log(10));
                            Double yLog = yOrd - logValue*133.33333333;
                            Sample NormedSampleLa=new Sample("La",yLog);
                            sampleREE.add(NormedSampleLa);
                       }
                    } 

       } finally {
       }
}

   public String LaS, CeS, PrS, NdS, PmS, SmS, EuS, GdS, TbS, DyS, HoS, ErS, TmS, YbS, LuS;
   public String element, elementValue;
   public Double yOrd=450.0;
```

}

Comment: You don´t need that empty finally block ;-) (at least not for the "new" java 7 resource handling you used)

Comment: I will take a look later to the exceptions treatment. Fixed.